# keep the selected option after form submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have this php code , it shows a series of mysql rows as options for a dropdown menu in a form

```
$sql2="SELECT DISTINCT nombre FROM series where premium='0'";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql2);
<form  action="series.php" method="GET">
<select id="prueba "name="serie"><?php
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo  $row["nombre"]; 
        echo '<option value="'.$row["nombre"].'">'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

and what i want is that when a user submits the form , $row["nombre"] gets selected 
if (isset$_GET["serie"])) '.$row["nombre"].';
something like that , how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to select the posted value:

```
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (!empty($_GET['serie']) && $row['nombre'] == $_GET['serie']) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["nombre"].'">'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Missing a parenthesis. Fixed now.

Comment: Also, you don't need the echo $row["nombre"]; in the while loop.

Comment: Hm, i don't think that there are errors now. Please, try again copying this snippet.

Comment: Nice! If the answer worked for you then please consider marking the answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the selected attribute:

```
$sql2="SELECT DISTINCT nombre FROM series where premium='0'";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql2);
<form  action="series.php" method="GET">
<select id="prueba "name="serie"><?php
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo  $row["nombre"]; 
        echo '<option value="'.$row["nombre"].'"';
        echo (isset($_GET["serie"]) && $_GET['serie'] == $row["nombre"]) ? " selected" : "";
        echo '>'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

By your question im actually not sure what your condition is, but I hope you get the point.

Comment: echo (isset($_GET["serie"].$row["nombre"])) ? " selected" : ""; error in this line , actually i tried something like this but i read here that you can't use isset this way in an echo , you had to do it some other way i don't remember

Comment: Actually this line is alright. It just depends on what your condition is.

<?php
$var = "abc";
 echo (isset($var) && $var == "abc") ? " selected" : "";

Works perfectly fine.

You might want to look at my updated answer. I think thats the condition you wanted.

Comment: I think it should be: echo ( ( isset($_GET["serie"]) && $_GET['serie'] == $row["nombre"]) ? " selected" : "" );